# 404 error when trying to list category entries

Tags: entries, 404, categories

I've been trying for days to figure this thing out. I'm building a News section in the site, and under news are 3 categories: Updates, Events, Archive. When you click on one of the categories, i want it to list all the entries where it is under that category, but no matter what I try I just get a 404 error.

Here are my settings:
Channel short name: news
Group Assignments > Category group: News
Category Group Name: News
News Categories: updates, events, archive

And here is my current code (though I've tried many many different options and version:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      {embed="Pages/styles"}
      {embed="Pages/scripts"}
      {exp:channel:entries channel="news" dynamic="no" limit="1"}
      <title>{site_name} - {structure:page:title}</title>
      <meta name='keywords' content='{news-keywords}' />
      <meta name='description' content='{news-description}' />
      {/exp:channel:entries}
  </head>
  <body>
      {embed="Pages/header"}
      <main>
          <nav id="breadcrumbs">{exp:structure:breadcrumb inc_home="no" here_as_title="yes" separator=":"}{/exp:structure:breadcrumb}</nav>
          {exp:channel:entries channel="news" category="{segment_2_category_id}" dynamic="no"}
              <article>
                  <h1>{title}</h1>
                  <p>Author: {author} Posted: {entry_date format="%M %j, %Y"} at {entry_date format='%h:%i %A'}</p>
                  <p>{news-content}</p>
              </article>
          {/exp:channel:entries}
          <aside>
              <ul>
                  <li>Categories</li>
                  {exp:channel:categories channel="news" style="linear"}
                  <li><a href="{path='news/{category_url_title}'}">{category_name}</a></li>
                  {/exp:channel:categories}
              </ul>
          </aside>
      </main>
      {embed="Pages/footer}
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The channel:entries tag doesn't have a `category_url_title` parameter. If you want to use the URL structure you're after, you'll need to install [Low Seg2Cat](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat). Once installed, you can use `{segment_2_category_id}` to get the right category ID associated with the second segment (which points to a category URL title). Add `dynamic="no"` to the tag as well, since you're telling EE what to display, instead of letting EE guess, based on the URI.

Also, you're missing a closing quote on your opening tag. And I think you need to add `style="linear"` to your channel:categories tag, in order to avoid nested `<li>` elements.

So, with Low Seg2Cat installed, this is how it should look:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" category="{segment_2_category_id}" dynamic="no"}
    <article>
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        <p>Author: {author} Posted: {entry_date format="%M %j, %Y"} at {entry_date format='%h:%i %A'}</p>
        <p>{news-content}</p>
    </article>
{/exp:channel:entries}
<aside>
    <ul>
        <li>Categories</li>
        {exp:channel:categories channel="news" style="linear"}
        <li><a href="{path='news/{category_url_title}'}">{category_name}</a></li>
        {/exp:channel:categories}
    </ul>
</aside>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I'm still getting the "Status: 404 Page Not Found" error. I actually already installed Low Seg2Cat, and I've left its settings to its default.

Comment: I should also mention that if I manually enter in a category's id (instead of {segment_2_category_id}) it will list the entries there. It's just not pulling the information via segment2 in the url. 

Here is the site I'm testing it on: http://www.oneoffs.co/news/
Yes, the site is only the bare-bones of code, just building a template for functionality so far. I've just updated my original post to reflect my current code.

Comment: Ah, you're using Structure. That changes the way URI segments work. You'll need to make the second segment after `news` capable of being dynamic. I'm no Structure expert, so I don't know where/how to do that.

Comment: I am using Structure, yes.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me something to investigate some more.